# Lex/Yacc failed to compile

Tags: yacc

I'm trying to create a compiler using Flex Windows (lex and yacc) for my school assignment, and I've successfully generated the .l and .y files. However, when trying to build the parser using Lex+Yacc build, I've encountered this error:

```
    y.tab.h:48:4: error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'enum'
```

I've seen a similar problem in the following website:
https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/861576-error-expected-identifier-before-token
But the place of occurrence for the error is different. Any suggestions about how I can solve this? Thanks in advance!

For reference, here is an excerpt from my y.tab.h file :

```
   ...
    #ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
    # define YYTOKENTYPE
   /* Put the tokens into the symbol table, so that GDB and other debuggers
      know about them.  */
   enum yytokentype {  //place of error
     NEWLINE = 258,
     VAR = 259,
     INC = 260,
     DEC = 261,
     GTR = 262,
     LSR = 263,
     EQL = 264,
     NEQ = 265,
     LAND = 266,
     LOR = 267,
     NOT = 268,
     INT = 269,
     FLOAT = 270,
     BOOL = 271,
     STRING = 272,
     PRINTLN = 273,
     PRINT = 274,
     TRUE = 275,
     FALSE = 276,
     IF = 277,
     FOR = 278,
     IFX = 279,
     ELSE = 280,
     END = 281,
     GEQ = 282,
     LEQ = 283,
     REM_ASSIGN = 284,
     QUO_ASSIGN = 285,
     MUL_ASSIGN = 286,
     SUB_ASSIGN = 287,
     ADD_ASSIGN = 288,
     INT_LIT = 289,
     FLOAT_LIT = 290,
     IDENT = 291,
     STRING_LIT = 292
   };
   ...
```

And these are my .l and .y files:

```
    ***Compiler_B24051260_HW2.l***
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include "common.h"
    #include "y.tab.h"  /* header file generated by bison */
    extern YYSTYPE yylval;


    #define YY_NO_UNPUT
    #define YY_NO_INPUT

   %}

letter [a-zA-Z_]
digit [0-9]
id {letter}+({letter}|{digit})*
inumber {digit}+
fnumber {digit}*\.{digit}+
ws           [ \t]+
quota        [\"]
newline      \n
misc         [^a-zA-Z0-9]-\n
symbols      [\%\^\#\&\!\@\*]
line_over    [\./]

%x STR
%x CMT
%option yylineno


%%

"var"  { return VAR; }
"int32"    { return INT; }
"float32"  { return FLOAT; }
"bool"    { return BOOL; }
"true"    { return TRUE;}
"false"    { return FALSE;} 
"println"  { return PRINTLN; }
"print"    { return PRINT; }
"if"    { return IF; }
"else"    { return ELSE; }
"for"    { return FOR; }
"string"    { return STRING; }
"\""        { BEGIN(STR);
                return '"';
            }
<STR>"\""   { BEGIN(INITIAL);
                return '"';
            }
<STR>[^\"]* { //yylval.usage->kind = kind_char;
              //yylval.usage->usage.use_char = strdup(yytext);
              yylval.s_val = strdup(yytext);
                return STRING_LIT;
            }


"/*"        { BEGIN(CMT); }
<CMT>"*/"   { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<CMT>\n     {;}
<CMT>.      {;}
"//".*      {;}
"+"    { return '+'; }
"-"    { return '-'; }
"*"    { return '*'; }
"/"    { return '/'; }
"%"    { return '%'; }
"++"   { return INC; }
"--"   { return DEC; }
">"    { return '>'; }
"<"    { return '<'; }
">="   { return GEQ; }
"<="   { return LEQ; }
"=="   { return EQL; }
"!="   { return NEQ; }
"="    { return '='; }
"+="   { return ADD_ASSIGN; }
"-="   { return SUB_ASSIGN; }
"*="   { return MUL_ASSIGN; }
"/="   { return QUO_ASSIGN; }
"%="   { return REM_ASSIGN; }
"&&"   { return LAND ; }
"||"   { return LOR; }
"!"    { return NOT; }
"("    { return '('; }
")"    { return ')'; }
"["    { return '['; }
"]"    { return ']'; }
"{"    { return '{';}
"}"    { return '}';}
";"    { return ';'; }
","    { return ','; }


\n   { return NEWLINE; yylineno++;}
[ \t]+      {;}

{id}         { //yylval.usage->kind = kind_char;
               //yylval.usage->usage.use_char = strdup(yytext);
               yylval.s_val = strdup(yytext);
           printf ("current token:%s", yytext);
                return IDENT;
         }
{inumber}   { //yylval.usage->kind = kind_int;
              //yylval.usage->usage.use_in = atoi(yytext);

              yylval.i_val = atoi(yytext);
                return INT_LIT;
            }
{fnumber}   {   //printf ("%.6f", yytext);
                //yylval.usage->kind = kind_float;
                //yylval.usage->usage.use_fl = atof(yytext);
        yylval.f_val = atof(yytext);
                return FLOAT_LIT;
            }


{ws}         {;}


<<EOF>>     { static int once = 0;
                if (once++) {
                    yyterminate();
                }
                yylineno++;
                //return END;
            }

.           {;}

%%
int yywrap(void)
{
return 1;
}
```

***Compiler_B24051260_HW2.y***

```
%{
    #include "common.h" //Extern variables that communicate with lex
    #include <string.h>
    //#include <ctype.h>
    //#include <math.h>

     //#define YYDEBUG 1
     //int yydebug = 1;
    //#define YYSTYPE struct NonTer
    //#define YYSTYPE char *

    extern int yylineno;
    extern int yychar;

    extern int yylex();
    extern FILE *yyin;

    struct {
      enum { is_int, is_float, is_char, nothing } type;
      union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char *cval; 
      } val;
    } my_array[52][7];



    //struct

    //int symbols[52][7];
    //int symbolVal (char ID);
    //void Update (char ID, int num);
    int scope=0;
    int id_index=0;
    int arr_index=0;
    int id_type=0;
    int addr=0;
    int ele_type=0;


    void yyerror (char const *s)
    {
        printf("error: in line %d with token %d: %s\n", yylineno, yychar, s);
    }

    static void create_symbol();
    static void insert_symbol(char *val ,int scope, int id_index, int data_type, int address, int line, int ele_type); 
    static int lookup_symbol(char *val);
    static void dump_symbol();

%}

%error-verbose





%union
{


    //int i_val;
    //float f_val;
    //char *s_val;
    //struct NonTer* usage;
}


%token NEWLINE
%token VAR 
%token INC DEC GTR LSR EQL NEQ
%token LAND LOR NOT
%token INT FLOAT BOOL STRING
%token PRINTLN PRINT
%token TRUE FALSE
%token IF FOR
%nonassoc IFX
%nonassoc ELSE
//%token INT_LIT /*FLOAT_LIT*/IDENT STRING_LIT
%token END

%left '<' '>' '=' LEQ GEQ
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left ADD_ASSIGN SUB_ASSIGN MUL_ASSIGN QUO_ASSIGN REM_ASSIGN

%union {
    int i_val;
    float f_val;
    char *s_val;

}


/*%token <nval>  INT_LIT
%token <nval>  FLOAT_LIT
%token <nval>  IDENT STRING_LIT*/

/*%token <usage>  INT_LIT
%token <usage>  FLOAT_LIT
%token <usage>  IDENT STRING_LIT*/

%token <i_val>  INT_LIT
%token <f_val>  FLOAT_LIT
%token <s_val>  IDENT STRING_LIT


//%token <f_val>  FLOAT_LIT

%start Program

%% 
Program
    : StatementList END{;}
;

StatementList
    : Statement StatementList {;}
    | Statement {;}
;

Statement
    : Exprs {;}
;

Exprs 
    : Expr NEWLINE Exprs
    | Expr


Expr
    : Arith {;}
    | Declares {;}
    | Change {;}
    | Print {;}  
    | Logic {;}
    | Assign {;}
    | NEWLINE {;}
;

Print 
    : PRINTLN '(' IDENT ')' { printf ("PRINTLN id\n"); }
    | PRINTLN '(' INT_LIT ')' {  printf ("PRINTLN int\n"); }
    | PRINTLN '(' FLOAT_LIT ')' {; }
    | PRINTLN '(' Logic ')'{ printf ("PRINTLN bool\n");; }
    | PRINTLN '(' Arith ')'{;}    
;

Logic
    : LateLogic LOR LateLogic { printf ("LOR\n");}
    | LateLogic {;}
;
LateLogic
    : LateLogic LAND LateLogic {printf ("LAND\n");}
    | Compare {;}
    | Is_not {;}
;
Compare
    : Arith '>' Arith {printf ("GTR\n");}
    | Arith '<' Arith {printf ("LSR\n");}
    | Arith EQL Arith {printf ("EQL\n");}
    | Arith NEQ Arith {printf ("NEQ\n");}
    | Arith GEQ Arith {printf ("GEQ\n");}
    | Arith LEQ Arith {printf ("LEQ\n");}
;

Is_not
    : NOT TRUE {printf ("TRUE\n");
                printf ("NOT\n");}
    | NOT FALSE {printf ("FALSE\n");
                 printf ("NOT\n");}
    | NOT Is_not {printf ("NOT\n");}

Arith
    : Arith '+' Term {printf ("ADD\n");}
    | Arith '-' Term {printf ("SUB\n");}
    | Term      
;

Term
    : Factor 
    | Term '*' Factor {printf ("MUL\n");}
    | Term '/' Factor {printf ("QUO\n");}
    | Term '%' Factor {printf ("REM\n");;}

;

Factor
    : '(' Arith ')' {;}
    | IDENT { int e = lookup_symbol($1);
        printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n" ,$1, e);}     
    | INT_LIT { printf ("INT_LIT %d\n", $1);}
    | '+' INT_LIT {printf ("INT_LIT %d\n", $2);
                printf ("POS\n");}
    | '-' INT_LIT {printf ("INT_LIT %d\n", $2);
                printf ("NEG\n");}
    | FLOAT_LIT {printf ("FLOAT_LIT %.6f\n", $1);}
    | '+' FLOAT_LIT {printf ("FLOAT_LIT %.6f\n", $2);
                printf ("POS\n");}
    | '-' FLOAT_LIT {printf ("FLOAT_LIT %.6f\n", $2);
                printf ("NEG\n");}    
;


Declares
    : VAR IDENT INT NEWLINE{
            //char a = $2.use_char;
            printf("> Insert {%s} into symbol table (scope level: %d)\n", $2, scope);
            id_type = 1;
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index, id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr = addr+1;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT FLOAT NEWLINE{
            printf("> Insert {%s} into symbol table (scope level: %d)\n", $2, scope);
            id_type = 2;
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index, id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT INT '=' INT_LIT NEWLINE {
            printf ("INT_LIT %d\n", $5);
        printf("> Insert {%s} into symbol table (scope level: %d)\n", $2, scope);
        id_type = 1;
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index,id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT FLOAT '=' FLOAT_LIT NEWLINE {
            printf ("FLOAT_LIT %.5d\n", $5);
        printf("> Insert {%s} into symbol table (scope level: %d)\n", $2, scope);
            id_type = 2;
        ele_type=0; // has nothing
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index,id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }

    | VAR IDENT '[' INT_LIT ']'INT NEWLINE { 
        id_type=3;  //is array
            ele_type = 1; //is int
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index,id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT STRING NEWLINE{            
            id_type = 4; //is string
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index, id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT BOOL '=' TRUE NEWLINE {
            printf ("TRUE\n");
        id_type = 5; // is bool
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index,id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
    | VAR IDENT BOOL '=' FALSE NEWLINE {
            printf ("FALSE\n");
        id_type = 5;
        ele_type=0;
            insert_symbol($2,scope,id_index,id_type, addr, yylineno, ele_type);
        addr++;
        id_index++;
        arr_index++;
        //printf ("next address %d at array line %d", addr, id_index);
        }
;


Change 
    : IDENT INC { int e = lookup_symbol($1);
                 printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);
                 printf ("INC\n");}
    | IDENT DEC {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
                 printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);
                 printf ("DEC\n");}
;

Assign
    : Num_assign {;} 
    | IDENT  {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
      '=' Item {            
            printf ("ASSIGN\n");}

;

Item
    : TRUE {printf ("TRUE\nASSIGN\n");}
    | FALSE {printf ("FALSE\nASSIGN\n");}
    | '"' STRING_LIT '"' {printf ("STRING_LIT %s\n", $2);}
    | Num {;}
;
Num_assign
    : IDENT {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
       ADD_ASSIGN Num {
            printf ("ADD_ASSIGN\n");}
    | IDENT {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
       SUB_ASSIGN Num {
            printf ("SUB_ASSIGN\n");}
    | IDENT {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
       MUL_ASSIGN Num {
            printf ("MUL_ASSIGN\n");}
    | IDENT {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
       QUO_ASSIGN Num {
            printf ("QUO_ASSIGN\n");}
    | IDENT {int e = lookup_symbol($1);
            printf ("IDENT (name=%s, address=%d)\n", $1, e);}
       REM_ASSIGN Num {
            printf ("REM_ASSIGN\n");}
;

Num
    : INT_LIT {printf ("INT_LIT %d\n", $1);}
    | FLOAT_LIT { printf ("FLOAT_LIT %.6f\n", $1);} //debug: precision setting
;




%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    } else {
        yyin = stdin;
    }

    int a;
    for (a=0; a<52; a++) {
        my_array[a][0].type= nothing;
        my_array[a][0].val.ival = -1;
    }

    yylineno = 0;
    yyparse();

    dump_symbol();
    printf("Total lines: %d\n", yylineno);
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

static void create_symbol() {
}

static void insert_symbol(char *val ,int scope, int id_index, int data_type, int address, int line, int ele_type) {


    my_array[arr_index][0].type = is_int;
    my_array[arr_index][0].val.ival = id_index;
    my_array[arr_index][1].type = is_char;
    my_array[arr_index][1].val.cval = val;
    my_array[arr_index][2].type = is_int;
    my_array[arr_index][2].val.ival = data_type;

    my_array[arr_index][3].type = is_int;
    my_array[arr_index][3].val.ival = address;
    my_array[arr_index][4].type = is_int;
    my_array[arr_index][4].val.ival = line;
    my_array[arr_index][5].type = is_int;
    my_array[arr_index][5].val.ival = ele_type;

}

static int lookup_symbol(char *val) {
    //printf ("%s\n", val);
    int c=0;
    int d=0;

    while (my_array[c][0].type!=nothing) {
        //printf ("%s\n", my_array[c][1].val.cval);
    int result = strcmp(my_array[c][1].val.cval, val);
        //printf("strcmp(my_array[c][1].val.cval, val) = %d\n", result);
        if (result==0) {
        d = my_array[c][3].val.ival;
        //printf ("%d\n", d);
        break;
    }
    c++;
    }
    return d;
}

static void dump_symbol() {
    printf("> Dump symbol table (scope level: %d)\n", 0);
    printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%s\n",
           "Index", "Name", "Type", "Address", "Lineno", "Element type");
    int b=0;
    char type[10];
    char element[10];
    int r = my_array[b][2].val.ival;
    int s = my_array[b][5].val.ival;
    while (my_array[b][0].type!=nothing) {
        //printf ("current type: %d, %d\n", my_array[b][2].val.ival, my_array[b][5].val.ival);

        if (r==1) {
        strcpy (type, "int32");
    } 
    else if (r==2) {
        strcpy (type, "float32");
    }
    else if (r==3) {
        strcpy (type, "array");
    }
    else if (r==4) {
        strcpy (type, "string");
    }


    if (s==0) {
        strcpy (element, "-");
    } 
    else if (s==1) {
        strcpy (element, "int32");
    }
    else if (s==2) {
        strcpy (element, "float32");
    }

    //printf ("%s\n",type);
    //printf ("%s\n",element);
        printf("%-10d%-10s%-10s%-10d%-10d%-10s\n",
            b, my_array[b][1].val.cval, type, my_array[b][3].val.ival, my_array[b][4].val.ival, element);
    b++;
    }

}
```

edit: full y.tab.h file:

```
/* A Bison parser, made by GNU Bison 2.7.  */

/* Bison interface for Yacc-like parsers in C

      Copyright (C) 1984, 1989-1990, 2000-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

/* As a special exception, you may create a larger work that contains
   part or all of the Bison parser skeleton and distribute that work
   under terms of your choice, so long as that work isn't itself a
   parser generator using the skeleton or a modified version thereof
   as a parser skeleton.  Alternatively, if you modify or redistribute
   the parser skeleton itself, you may (at your option) remove this
   special exception, which will cause the skeleton and the resulting
   Bison output files to be licensed under the GNU General Public
   License without this special exception.

   This special exception was added by the Free Software Foundation in
   version 2.2 of Bison.  */

#ifndef YY_YY_Y_TAB_H_INCLUDED
# define YY_YY_Y_TAB_H_INCLUDED
/* Enabling traces.  */
#ifndef YYDEBUG
# define YYDEBUG 0
#endif
#if YYDEBUG
extern int yydebug;
#endif

/* Tokens.  */
#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
   /* Put the tokens into the symbol table, so that GDB and other debuggers
      know about them.  */
   enum yytokentype {
     NEWLINE = 258,
     LB = 259,
     RB = 260,
     VAR = 261,
     INC = 262,
     DEC = 263,
     GTR = 264,
     LSR = 265,
     EQL = 266,
     NEQ = 267,
     LAND = 268,
     LOR = 269,
     NOT = 270,
     INT = 271,
     FLOAT = 272,
     BOOL = 273,
     STRING = 274,
     PRINTLN = 275,
     PRINT = 276,
     TRUE = 277,
     FALSE = 278,
     IF = 279,
     FOR = 280,
     ELSE = 281,
     IFX = 282,
     ELSEX = 283,
     FIRST = 284,
     SECOND = 285,
     END = 286,
     GEQ = 287,
     LEQ = 288,
     REM_ASSIGN = 289,
     QUO_ASSIGN = 290,
     MUL_ASSIGN = 291,
     SUB_ASSIGN = 292,
     ADD_ASSIGN = 293,
     INT_LIT = 294,
     FLOAT_LIT = 295,
     IDENT = 296,
     STRING_LIT = 297
   };
#endif
/* Tokens.  */
#define NEWLINE 258
#define LB 259
#define RB 260
#define VAR 261
#define INC 262
#define DEC 263
#define GTR 264
#define LSR 265
#define EQL 266
#define NEQ 267
#define LAND 268
#define LOR 269
#define NOT 270
#define INT 271
#define FLOAT 272
#define BOOL 273
#define STRING 274
#define PRINTLN 275
#define PRINT 276
#define TRUE 277
#define FALSE 278
#define IF 279
#define FOR 280
#define ELSE 281
#define IFX 282
#define ELSEX 283
#define FIRST 284
#define SECOND 285
#define END 286
#define GEQ 287
#define LEQ 288
#define REM_ASSIGN 289
#define QUO_ASSIGN 290
#define MUL_ASSIGN 291
#define SUB_ASSIGN 292
#define ADD_ASSIGN 293
#define INT_LIT 294
#define FLOAT_LIT 295
#define IDENT 296
#define STRING_LIT 297



#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef union YYSTYPE
{
/* Line 2058 of yacc.c  */
#line 75 "hw2_demo.y"



    int i_val;
    float f_val;
    char *s_val;
    //struct NonTer* usage;


/* Line 2058 of yacc.c  */
#line 151 "y.tab.h"
} YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define yystype YYSTYPE /* obsolescent; will be withdrawn */
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
#endif

extern YYSTYPE yylval;

#ifdef YYPARSE_PARAM
#if defined __STDC__ || defined __cplusplus
int yyparse (void *YYPARSE_PARAM);
#else
int yyparse ();
#endif
#else /* ! YYPARSE_PARAM */
#if defined __STDC__ || defined __cplusplus
int yyparse (void);
#else
int yyparse ();
#endif
#endif /* ! YYPARSE_PARAM */

#endif /* !YY_YY_Y_TAB_H_INCLUDED  */
```

Comment: seems you forgot a ';', look at the generate lexer and should be easy to find out how fix

Comment: @gtosto By generate lexer, do you mean to check the .l file?  Because after checking, I can't find any lines that is missing ';'.

Comment: I mean the generated c file (.c). Anyway  can you post the complete  y.tab.h file ?

Comment: @gtosto I've included the file now.

Comment: I saw, but unlikely I cannot find out the problem.

Comment: @gtosto That's okay. Thanks for your responses anyway!

Comment: It looks like the error about the missing semicolon appears at the beginning of the first line of the header file that has actual code in it (the enum definition). That means a semicolon is actually missing in a file that includes the header on the line before the include. I see that in your lexer you include `y.tab.h` right after `common.h`. So my spider senses tell me that there's a missing semicolon at the end of `common.h`. If that's not it, you'll have to post a proper [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I did what you asked, and it turns out that I'm missing a semicolon after the union declaration in "common.h".